# Sorting a list in Groovy in an unusual way

Tags: sorting, groovy

I have a list of, let's say `[Cat, Dog, Cow, Horse]`, that I want to be sorted in the following way

- if `Cat` is on the list it should come first
- if `Cow` is on the list it should come second
- The rest of the elements should come after in alphabetic order.

Any suggestions how this could be done in Groovy?

Comment: If Cow is in the list and Cat is not, does Cow still need to be in the second place?  What if the list is just `['Cow']`?

Comment: No. Then cow should be first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tim's answer is pretty clever. I'm personally more a fan of just using list operations as the code it generates is slightly easier to read.

```
def highPriority = [ 'Cat', 'Cow' ]

def list = [ 'Armadillo', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cow', 'Cat' ]

def remainder = ( list - highPriority ).sort()

list.retainAll( highPriority )

list.sort{ highPriority.indexOf( it ) } + remainder
```

That will give you Cow twice. If you don't want duplicates, using intersect is fairly simple.

```
def highPriority = [ 'Cat', 'Cow' ]

def list = [ 'Armadillo', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cow', 'Cat' ]

list.intersect( highPriority ).sort{ highPriority.indexOf( it ) } + ( list - highPriority ).sort()
```

Comment: I agree with you Tomas. Since I'm pretty new to groovy your solution is easier for me to follow. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
// Define our input list
def list = [ 'Armadillo', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cow' ]

// Define a closure that will do the sorting
def sorter = { String a, String b, List prefixes=[ 'Cat', 'Cow' ] ->
  // Get the index into order for a and b
  // if not found, set to being Integer.MAX_VALUE
  def (aidx,bidx) = [a,b].collect { prefixes.indexOf it }.collect {
    it == -1 ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : it
  }
  // Compare the two indexes.
  // If they are the same, compare alphabetically
  aidx <=> bidx ?: a <=> b
}

// Create a new list by sorting using our closure
def sorted = list.sort false, sorter

// Print it out
println sorted
```

That prints:

```
[Cat, Cow, Cow, Armadillo, Dog, Horse, Zebra]
```

I've commented it to try and explain each step it takes.  By adding the default prefix items as an optional parameter on the `sorter` closure, it means we can do stuff like this to change the default:

```
// Use Dog, Zebra, Cow as our prefix items
def dzc = list.sort false, sorter.rcurry( [ 'Dog', 'Zebra', 'Cow' ] )
println dzc
```

Which then prints the list sorted as:

```
[Dog, Zebra, Cow, Cow, Armadillo, Cat, Horse]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another alternative that feels simpler to me:

```
// smaller values get sorted first
def priority(animal) {
    animal in ['Cat', 'Cow'] ? 0 : 1
}

def list = [ 'Armadillo', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cow' ]

def sorted = list.sort{ a, b -> priority(a) <=> priority(b) ?: a <=> b }

assert sorted == ['Cat', 'Cow', 'Cow', 'Armadillo', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Zebra']
```

Comment: What happens if you want Cow before Cat in your priority list? ;)

Comment: Give Cow priority 0, Cat priority 1, everything else priority 2.

Comment: In groovy: `[Cow: 0, Cat: 1].withDefault{2}[animal]` :)

Comment: That's then kinda what my solution does... I tend to prefer it too ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I guess they're essentially the same.  I found pulling out the priority mapping into a separate method a bit more clear.

Comment: Sorry,I meant I prefer your map with default method rather than my index of with a catch ;) reading back my previous comment made me realise I founded like a smug idiot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have duplicate elements, you can try this:

```
def highPriority = [ 'Cat', 'Cow' ]
def list = [ 'Armadillo', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cat' ]
highPriority + list.minus(highPriority).sort()
```

Comment: What if Cat is missing from list?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired on [tomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9720817/581845):

```
def highPriority = [ 'Cat', 'Cow' ]
def list = [ 'Armadillo', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cow' ]

// Group animals by priority.
def groups = list.groupBy { it in highPriority ? it : 'rest' }
// High priority animals are sorted by priority and the rest alphabetically.
def sorted = highPriority.collectMany { groups[it] } + groups['rest'].sort()

assert sorted == ['Cat', 'Cow', 'Cow', 'Armadillo', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Zebra']
```

The `groups` variable is something like `[rest:[Armadillo, Dog, Zebra, Horse], Cat:[Cat], Cow:[Cow, Cow]]`.

Another, arguably less robust, solution might be:

```
def sorted = list.sort(false) { 
    def priority = highPriority.indexOf(it)
    if (priority == -1) priority = highPriority.size()
    // Sort first by priority and then by the value itself
    "$priority$it"
}
```

It is less robust in the sense that it sorts by strings like `"2Armadillo"`, `"0Cat"`, etc, and won't work if you have 9 or more high priority animals (because `"10Alpaca" < "9Eel"`. It would be cool if Groovy provided some sort of comparable tuple type, like [Python's tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/581845), so instead of returning `"$priority$it"` as the comparable key, one could return the tuple `(priority, it)`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but today i found that Groovy has a, rather undocumented, [`OrderBy`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/OrderBy.html) comparator that can be used in this case:

```
def highPriority = ['Cow', 'Cat']
def list = ['Armadillo', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cow', 'Zebra', 'Horse', 'Cow']

def sorted = list.sort new OrderBy([{ -highPriority.indexOf(it) }, { it }])

assert sorted == ['Cat', 'Cow', 'Cow', 'Armadillo', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Zebra']
```

The `OrderBy` comparator first compares the animals using their index in the `highPriority` list negated (therefore the animals that are not high priority (i.e. index -1) are moved to the back of the list) and if the indexes are equal it compares them by the identity function `{it}`, which, as animals are strings, sorts them alphabetically.