# Isolating lists based on value in python3

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a set of lists that I want to compare firstly the sum values of the lists and then individual elements in the event of two or more lists having the same value.

```
my_list1 = [2, 3, 2, 4, 5]
my_list2 = [1, 3, 2, 3, 2]
my_list3 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
my_list4 = [3, 2, 2, 4, 5]
```

Logic testing for an outright winner is fine but the problem I am having is isolating the lists in the event of a draw – So in the scenario above `my_list1` and `my_list4` would be isolated for further logic testing as their totals both come to `16`.

This is what I have so far

```
my_list1=[1,1,2,2,2]
my_list2=[1,1,1,1,2]
my_list3=[2,2,1,1,2]


my_list1Total=sum(my_list1)
my_list2Total=sum(my_list2)
my_list3Total=sum(my_list3)

if my_list1Total>my_list2Total and my_list1Total>my_list3Total:
    print("List one has the higest score")
elif my_list2Total>my_list1Total and my_list2Total>my_list3Total:
    print("List two has the higest score")
elif my_list3Total>my_list2Total and my_list3Total>my_list1Total:
    print("List three has the higest score")
else:
   print("Draw")

##so now I want to compare the lists with the same total but this time by the first element in the list. In this case it would be my_list1[0] and my_list3[0] that would be compared next.  The winner having the highest value in position 0 of the drawing lists
```

Comment: What have you tried, what is the output you're getting and what did you expect instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a single list which holds all of your lists. Then you can use `max` on that list to find the largest element. Or, if you want the index of the list and not just its value, you can write a max-like method and use that instead.

```
#like the built-in function `max`, 
#but returns the index of the largest element
#instead of the largest element itself.
def index_of_max(seq, key=lambda item:item):
    return max(range(len(seq)), key=lambda idx: key(seq[idx]))

lists = [
    [2, 3, 2, 4, 5],
    [1, 3, 2, 3, 2],
    [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    [3, 2, 2, 4, 5]
]

idx = index_of_max(lists, key=lambda item: (sum(item), item[0]))
#add one to this result because Python lists are zero indexed, 
#but the original numbering scheme started at one.
print "List # {} is largest.".format(idx+1)
```

Result:

```
List # 4 is largest.
```

---

A little explanation about `key`: it's a function that you pass to `max`, that it uses to determine the comparative value of two items in the sequence. It calls key(someItem) on both items, and whichever item has a larger result, is considered the maximum item between the two of them. The key function I used here returns a tuple. Due to the way [tuple comparison works in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/python-tuple-comparison), comparison is done by sum first, then using the first element of each list as a tie breaker.

If you're thinking "but what if the first elements are also the same? I want to use each following item as a tie breaker", then you can modify the key to compare all of them in turn.

```
idx = index_of_max(lists, key=lambda item: [sum(item)]+item)
```