# Mimic the array swaps from a sort

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
l = [0, 1, 3, 2]

l2 = ['foo', 3, 'bar', 10]
```

If I say `sorted(l)`, I will get `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. It will swap the last two elements.

How can I apply the same row swaps to `l2`? I.e., I want `l2` to be `['foo', 3, 10, 'bar']`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zip`, unpack tuple and a list comprehension to achieve the results:

```
[y for x, y in sorted(zip(l, l2))]
```

Comment: so when you say `sorted` on a list of tuples it will sort the list based on the first values of each tuple?

Comment: Tuples are compared as a sequence, which means compare first element first, if equal, compare second, etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/python-tuple-comparison.

Comment: Note that if two elements of `l` are equal, this will compare the elements of `l2` to determine the order. This may be undesirable, especially on Python 3, where trying to compare semantically unordered types will produce an exception. If this is a problem, you can use `[z for x, y, z in sorted(zip(l, range(len(l)), l2)]` to avoid comparing elements of `l2`.

Comment: Or, more simply, you can just use a `key` function as the tie breaker: `[y for x, y in sorted(zip(l, l2), key=itemgetter(0))]`.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

```
>>> l, l2 = zip(*sorted(zip(l, l2)))
>>> list(l)
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(l2)
['foo', 3, 10, 'bar']
```

---

**Explanation**

1. `zip` both the lists together

   ```
   >>> list(zip(l, l2))
   [(0, 'foo'), (1, 3), (2, 10), (3, 'bar')]
   ```
2. then sort them, (since we get tuples from `zip`, the first elements of tuples will be compared first and only if they are same, the second element will be compared. So the sorting effectively happens with the values of `l`)

   ```
   >>> sorted(zip(l, l2))
   [(0, 'foo'), (1, 3), (2, 10), (3, 'bar')]
   ```
3. and then unzip them,

   ```
   >>> list(zip(*sorted(zip(l, l2))))
   [(0, 1, 2, 3), ('foo', 3, 10, 'bar')]
   ```

   you can actually unzip over `l` and `l2`, like this

   ```
   >>> l, l2 = zip(*sorted(zip(l, l2)))
   >>> l, l2
   ((0, 1, 2, 3), ('foo', 3, 10, 'bar'))
   >>> list(l)
   [0, 1, 2, 3]
   >>> list(l2)
   ['foo', 3, 10, 'bar']
   ```

---

**Alternate approach**

You can actually sort the values along with the current index and then you can reconstruct the values like this

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 3, 2]
>>> l2 = ['foo', 3, 'bar', 10]
>>> l_s = sorted((value, idx) for idx, value in enumerate(l))
>>> l_s
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
>>> l = [value for value, idx in l_s]
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [l2[idx] for value, idx in l_s]
>>> l2
['foo', 3, 10, 'bar']
```