# finding maximum value in python list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples (list):

```
('2015-06-19', 3453455, 5, 'Scheduled')
('2015-05-19', 6786788, 6, 'Overdue')
('2015-04-19', 2342344, 2, 'Not Received')
('2015-03-19', 9438549, 0, 'Not Received')
('2015-02-19', 6348759, 7, 'Not Received')
```

When I run this, I get this:

```
>>> print(max(list))
('2015-06-19', 3453455, 5, 'Scheduled')
```

Obviously, max(list) determined the max based on the first value in the list of tuples. I'm just wondering if this is the default behavior of max(list) in regards to a list of tuples; to check only the first item in the tuple?

And, what if I wanted to return the tuple with the maximum based on the second item/column. How would I do that?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/python-tuple-comparison

Comment: it would check the subsequent values if the first value of any tuple matches.

Comment: You can change this behavior if you like: `max(tup_list, key= lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 16):

You can specify which field to use for comparison using lambdas

```
max(list,key=lambda x:x[1])
```

or alternatively, using `itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
max(list,key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: great answer, i always prefer `itemgetter` which is faster