# What exactly happens behind the scene in this case: list1 == list2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison-operators

I have two lists say list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] and list2 = [1,2,3,4,5]. If I do list1 == list2, it will return True. Suppose, I have one more list, say, list3 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] and if now I do list1 == list3, it will return False.

Can anyone please explain what is happening behind the scene? Are we comparing the values or references?

Comment: It does an ordered, element by element comparison, so obviously `[1, 2]` cannot equal `[2, 1]`. If you want unordered comparison, use sets.

Comment: The [accepted answer to the tuple question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/2932052) includes also **a section about list comparison**.

Comment: But there are also **differences**: `print [1,2]<[3], (1,2)<(3), (1,2)<(3,)`

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing each element, in the same order they appear in the list. What's happening behind the scene is something like:

```
if len(a) != len(b):
    return False
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != b[i]:
         return False          
return True
```

Comment: *`comparing each element`* "as long as they are equal" could be added. Do you refer to some official docs or just guessing?

Comment: @Wolf I'm just giving a (very) general idea, not referring any resource.

Comment: And one should assume the early break out as a fact?

Comment: @Wolf I will be very surprised otherwise. I trust Python developers that they did that..