# Python sort sprite dict into new dict sorted by name

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, pygame

I have a dict which is part of a `SpriteSheet` class of the attribute `sprite_info`. `sprite info` holds the names and location and xd/yd of each sprite on the sheet, i.e.

```
{'stone_Wall' : { 'x': '781', 'xd': '70', 'y': '568', 'yd': '70'} ... }
```

What I'd like to do is sort the dict by each name. In other words, there are other names in the list list `stone_Right` and `stone_Mid` and so on. The one thing they all have in common is `stone_`.

What's the most efficient way of doing this? My limited experience tells me to just go into a bunch of nested for-loops, but I know there's a better way.

Further clarification:

Once everything is sorted, I would like to separate the dict by name. Using my example, for any key that includes `stone` or `stone_`, add it to a new dict within the already existing dict.

Comment: Do you want to keep adding sprites after it's sorted? Or is it a one-off operation?

Comment: @PeterWood I do not. Other than separating the dict by keys, I will not be modifying it at all

Comment: Why do you think sorting it is required?

Comment: @IanAuld I'm going to make a list of dicts from this dict. Each dict within the list will contain key value pairs for each like name ('stone', 'stone_Center', etc). From that list, I will create a SpriteItem that contains a single dict from that list.

Comment: You should edit your question with some more of your code and actual problem you are trying to solve. This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a `dict`, as it uses its own sorted tree structure internally to keep efficient.

You can use `OrderedDict` which will keep track of the order elements are added.

To created a sorted `OrderedDict` from a `dict`, sort the key/value pairs from the `dict` based on the `key`.

edit: having thought a little more, `sorted` will compare tuples element by element, so item zero (the key) will be compared first, and will also be unique (as `dict` has unique keys), so we don't need to do anything clever with the `sorted` `key` parameter.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# from operator import itemgetter

sprites = dict()
# sorted_sprites = OrderedDict(sorted(sprites.items(), key=itemgetter(0)))
sorted_sprites = OrderedDict(sorted(sprites.items()))  # equivalent to above
```

[**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) is a built-in function which returns a `list` from a sequence.

The `key` parameter determines how to order the values in the sequence. As we are passing `sprites.items()` it is getting tuple pairs e.g. `('stone_Wall', { 'x': '781', 'xd': '70', 'y': '568', 'yd': '70'})`, so the key we want is the zero-th element of the tuple, `'stone_Wall'`.

[**`itemgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a functor which will retrieve a particular object (or objects) from a sequence. Here we ask it to get the zero-th.

However, as noted above, default tuple comparison will do this for us. See this related question: [python tuple comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/python-tuple-comparison)