# Dropping duplicate Pandas indices on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a large dataset where I'm using an id number as the index.  Before I start processing, I need to deal with a handful of duplicate ids that show up, but it needs to be done based on multiple criteria - essentially I want the *best* entry out of all the duplicate entries for each id.

In this example, I might first want it to take the duplicate with the most recent year - that will make id 1 unique.  But id 3 still has two values left, so then I want it to go onto the next condition - in this case we'll say maximum val:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'year':[2001, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2002], 'val':[7, 8, 9, 17, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id')

dups = df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)]

for id in dups.index.unique():
    current = dups.loc[id]
    max_yr = current['year'].max()
    #continue to process using multiple conditionals inside the loop
```

Where the result is this:

```
    val  year
id
1     7  2001
1     8  2002
2     9  2002
3    17  2001
3    11  2002
3    12  2002
```

Turns to this:

```
    val  year
id
1     8  2002
2     9  2002
3    12  2002
```

It works, but it's very inefficient and I feel like there must be a vectorized or at least better way to accomplish this.  A groupby could be incorporated, but I'm still not sure how I would do this without just looping through the groups.

Comment: are you after: `df.groupby(level=0).max()`?

Comment: No, it needs to consider multiple criteria on which duplicate to drop, leaving me with one *best* entry for every id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to add a compound column which will solely determine the best match. For example, if the first criterion is `max(year)`, and the second is `max(val)`, you can combine them into a `tuple` and take the largest value of that column. If some criterion is `min(X)`, then you can add `-X` to the tuple. ([tuples are compared element by element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/304209))

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id':[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'year':[2001, 2002, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2002], 'val':[7, 8, 9, 17, 11, 12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('id')
df['year_val'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row.year, row.val), axis=1)
df.reset_index().groupby('id').apply(
    lambda df: df[df['year_val'] == df['year_val'].max()]).drop(
    ['year_val'], axis=1).set_index('id')

    val  year
id           
1     8  2002
2     9  2002
3    12  2002
```

Comment: Oh, the tuple trick is perfect for this.  Thanks, I wasn't aware of that general Python functionality.

Comment: @JeffL. Glad it helps!