# compare tuples with values in python

Tags: python, comparison, tuples

Why a tuple can be compared with a number? What is the semantic of it? Does > and == have different semantic?

```
>>> (1,2)>0
True
>>> (1,2)>11111111111111
True
>>> (1,2)<5
False
>>> (1,2)>1.578
True
>>> (5,5)==5
False
>>> (5,5)!=5
True
```

This is not the same as comparing against a tuple with one element (which is compared [lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/2893839)):

```
>>> (5,5)>6
True
>>> (5,5)>(6,)
False
```

(Note: this is a different issue than comparing the tuple content against a value)

Comment: @MartijnPieters The question in not a duplicate of [How does Python compare string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int) altough the answer might be found there.

Comment: The answer is *exactly the same*. Arbitrary types are not compared on their value, only on their type name, with numbers before everything else. It doesn't matter if you have a tuple or a string here, numbers are still sorted first.

Comment: Given the specific title 'How does Python compare string and int?' I couldn't find it. It's a too broad answer for a more specific title. Search in SO is mostly based on title and that could easily be missed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying there. I didn't expect you to have found it directly, no.

Comment: I wouldn't have found it directly. Either we change the title for that answer to a more generic one, or we create a new broader question whose answer is similar to the already present one. That would remove all these duplicates.

Comment: If you want to discuss that, feel free to bring it to the attention of the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).