# Custom __lt__ method for comparisons

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to be able to sort a list of classes by one attribute, which happens to be another class Date. I have done some research and want to use the `sorted(list, key=lambda x:date)` method of sorting, but seeing as date is a class in itself how can I write an `__lt__` function in date to allow me to sort chronologically?

I want something along the lines of:

```
if self.year!= other.year:
    return self.year < other.year
elif self.month != pther.month
...
```

and so on.

Here is my Date class:

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, month, day, year, minute, hour, string):
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.year = year
        self.minute = minute
        self.hour = hour
        self.string = string
```

I should probably mention that this is the first time I have ever used Python, so I'm not very good at this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean list of objects?

Comment: Just curious: why are you storing dates like that instead of using the built-in dates?

Comment: @Sebastian Wozny Sorry, yes I meant objects

Comment: @bernie The assignment I am doing requires the date string (among other things) to be created in a C program and stored in a text file, but to be honest I had no idea about the built-in dates. Would they make this easier?

Comment: If you really want something of the sort, I think you're on a good track. Why not write it?

Comment: @SebastianWozny I was more having trouble with the syntax. Do you just continue writing what I had there into an `__lt__` function? and that will sort it when I call sorted?

Comment: yeah pretty much. you can simplify it to `return self.year <other.year or self.month<other.month or self.day<other.day` etc

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that now. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks again!

Comment: This question should really be closed. I'm glad you were able to solve your problem, however it is unlikely to ever help someone else.

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to compare two complex data structures is to compare tuples of their attributes, in the proper sort order. Try this:

```
class Date:
    def __init__(self, month, day, year, minute, hour, string):
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.year = year
        self.minute = minute
        self.hour = hour
        self.string = string
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (self.year, self.month, self.day, self.hour, self.minute) < \
               (other.year, other.month, other.day, other.hour, other.minute)

assert Date(4, 15, 2016, 30, 12, '') < \
       Date(4, 16, 2016, 0, 0, '') < \
       Date (1, 1, 2017, 59, 23, '')

assert not (Date(4, 16, 2016, 0, 0, '') < Date(4, 15, 2016, 30, 12, ''))
```

Of course, this only implements `<`. Depending upon the nature of your code, you may want to implement all of the other comparison functions, `>`, `==`, `!=`, etc. One convenient way to do this is to use the [`@functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) class decorator.

Reference:

- [How does tuple comparison work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering

Comment: I think you need parentheses there.

Comment: Where, precisely? And why do you think so?

Comment: Around your tuples. `<` has higher precedence than the comma, so instead of a boolean, you're actually returning a 9-element tuple with a `self.minute < other.year` boolean in the middle.

Comment: Also, it'd be a good idea to implement `__eq__` and put [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) on this class to get the rest of the comparison methods, or at least mention that it's important to remember them in real code.

Comment: @user2357112 - Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I propose adding a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) object to the class definition:

```
import datetime as dt, operator as op

class MyDate(object):
    def __init__(self, month, day, year, minute, hour, string):
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.year = year
        self.minute = minute
        self.hour = hour
        self.string = string
        self.dt = dt.datetime(self.year,self.month,self.day,self.hour,self.minute)

l = []
l.append(MyDate(2,17,2017,33,16,'somestring')) # not sure what `string` should be
l.append(MyDate(2,17,2017,37,16,'anotherstring'))
l.append(MyDate(2,17,2017,38,16,'yetanotherstring'))
```

Then you can use [`operator.attgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to sort, e.g.:

```
>>> sorted(l,key=op.attrgetter('dt'),reverse=True)
[<__main__.MyDate object at 0x000000000A4C84A8>, 
 <__main__.MyDate object at 0x000000000A4C8208>, 
 <__main__.MyDate object at 0x000000000A4C8978>]
```