# Comparing slices in python

Tags: python, slice

Inspecting the `slice` class in Python with `dir()`, I see that it has attributes `__le__` and `__lt__`. Indeed I saw that the following code works:

```
slice(1, 2) < slice(3, 4)
# True
```

However, I cannot see which logic is implemented for this comparison, nor its usecase. Can anyone point me to that?

I am not asking about tuple comparison. Even if slice and tuple are compared the same way, I don't think this makes my question a duplicate. What's more, I also asked for a possible usecase of slice comparison, which the suggested duplicate does not give.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I'm asking about slice, not tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `slice` reveals that the comparison is implemented by first converting the two objects into `(start, stop, step)` tuples, and then comparing those tuples:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6cca5c8459cc439cb050010ffa762a03859d3051/Objects/sliceobject.c#L598

As to the use cases, I am not sure of the authors' intent. I do note that there don't appear to be any comparison unit tests for anything other than equality:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6f0eb93183519024cb360162bdd81b9faec97ba6/Lib/test/test_slice.py#L87

Answer (score 2):

Comparing tuples : `(1, 2) < (3, 4)` returns `True` because `(1, 2) comes before (3, 4)`.

However, `(1, 2) < (0, 4)` returns `False` because `(1, 2) comes after (0, 4)`.

**NB:** `<` and `>` doesn't mean `smaller than` or `greater than`, but `is before` and `is after`.

So, in other words, you're comapring which is coming before and which is coming after.

**Some "odd" cases (Or, misleading cases within `<` and `>`):**

`(1, 2) < (3, 4, 5)` returns `True` because the missing value of the first tuple will be equal to `nil` value of the operation which is zero in this case. Or you can think of it that `(1, 2) come before (3, 4, 5)`.

And:

`(0, 1) < (1, 0)` will returns `True` because `(0, 1) comes before (1, 0)`

Another case:

`(0, 1, 20000) < (0, 3, 1)` will returns `True` because `(0, 1, 20000) comes before (0, 3, 1)`.

Same logic for `slice`, `list` and even `strings`.

For more informations, visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/3926995).

Comment: Regarding your "smaller than" comment, I do believe that lt and le stand for Less Than and Less or Equal. Do you confirm?

Comment: Yes i comfirm. `__lt__` will behave the same as `<`. the same for `<=` and `__le__`.

Comment: and < calls `__lt__`, so it indeed means "smaller than" (in python), no?

Comment: For `tuples`, `strings` and `lists` think of it like `comes before or comes after` not `smaller and greater` otherwise you'll face some odd cases. 
However, `<` ccalls `__lt__` and this special method behaves differently with its data

Answer (score 2):

[Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-64) only mentions that slice objects have three read-only attributes and one method. It does not mention any other properties of slices.

As mentioned by @NPE, CPython implementation indeed [provides](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6cca5c8459cc439cb050010ffa762a03859d3051/Objects/sliceobject.c#L598) a comparison for slice objects, which simply treats `slice` as a tuple of `(start, end, step)`. I've checked it with a small Python program which confirmed that:

```
vals = []
for a in range(-5, 5):
    for b in range(-5, 5):
        for c in range(-5, 5):
            vals.append((a, b, c))
for x in vals:
    for y in vals:
        assert (slice(*x) < slice(*y)) == (x < y)
```

However, that looks like a non-standard extension. For example, [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) also implements comparison for slices, but in a different way. Moreover, it looks like it [implements](https://bitbucket.org/jython/jython/src/91083509a11cdeadc9407b4d9a1ece2b8ffc45ce/src/org/python/core/PyObject.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#PyObject.java-1407) comparison for all possible pairs of objects by comparing objects of the same type by their `id`s, which is propagated to slices.

So, order of slices in Jython is non-deterministic. For example, the following snippet prints `True True` on my system with Jython and `True False` with CPython:

```
print(slice(1, 2) < slice(1, 3))
print(slice(1, 3) < slice(1, 2))
```

Summarizing: `__lt__` is implemented in CPython for some obscure reason, but it's not described anywhere in documentation and other implementations may behave not only differently, but "incorrectly" (in [mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)). So, one should not compare slices for inequality.