# Why doesn't Python3's range/slice object support containment testing for other ranges/slices?

Tags: python, range, slice

Python3's range objects support O(1) containment checking for integers [(1)](https://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-ideas/2014-October/029654.html) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3)

So one can do `15 in range(3, 19, 2)` and get the correct answer `True`

However, it doesn't support containment checking b/w two ranges

```
a = range(0, 10)
b = range(3, 7)
a in b # False
b in a # False, even though every element in b is also in a
a  < b # TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'
```

It seems that `b in a` is interpreted as *is any element in the range 'a' equal to the object 'b'?*

However, since the range cannot contain anything but integers, `range(...) in range(...)` will always return `False`. IMHO, such a query should be answered as *is every element in range 'b' also in range 'a'?* Given that range only stores the start, stop, step and length, this query can also be answered in O(1).

The slice object doesn't help either. It doesn't implement the `__contains__` method, and the `__lt__` method simply [compares two slices as tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565297/comparing-slices-in-python) (which makes no sense)

Is there a reason behind the current implementation of these, or is it just a "it happened to be implemented this way" thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the implementation of `__contains__` for ranges is [range_contains](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/rangeobject.c#L381-L389), which just checks if the given element is in the iterable, with a special case for longs.

As you have correctly observed, `e in b` returns true iff `e` is an element in `b`. Any other implementation, such as one that checks if `e` is a subset of `b`, would be ambiguous. This is especially problematic in Python, which doesn't require iterables be homogenous, and allows nested lists/tuples/sets/iterables.

Consider a world where your desired behavior was implemented. Now, suppose we have the following list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, (3, 4), 5]
ele1 = (3, 4)
ele2 = (2, 5)
```

In this case, what should `ele1 in my_list` and `ele2 in my_list` return? Your desired behavior makes it tedious to write code such as

```
if e in my_iterable:
    # ah! e must exist!
    my_iterable.remove(e)
```

A safer, better way is to keep the current behavior, and instead use a different type-sensitive operator to implement subset predicates:

```
x = set([1])
y = set([1,2])
x < y  # True
[1] < y  # raises a TypeError
```

Comment: Well, range isn't a container, but a sequence which only represents integer ranges. Although it is iterable, removing elements from it isn't allowed. So checking containment with a non number type can still be done. But you're right, it will create a lot of confusion and the cons outweigh the pros.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing `'b' containing 'a'` with `'a' being a subset of 'b'` - These are two different things.

`b containing a` means `range(0, 10)` is inside `b`. Let's say:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`a in b` is only true if the actual list `[1, 2, 3]` is in `[[1, 2, 3], 4, 5]`. So you're actually checking if the list itself is inside the other list, not that all the elements are in the other list.

A list `a` is a subset of `b` if all elements of `a` are inside `b`. In your example, `b` is a subset of `a`, yes, but the actual *list* `b` is not IN `a`.

If you want to do such methods, then it's probably recommended that you use a set data structure

Answer (score 1):

Range objects implement the collections.abc.Sequence, It supports containment tests.

```
a in b 
b in a
```

In this case, you are searching for Range object a in range b, vice versa. It should be false.