# Trying to compare where my sprite is in pygame to end the game

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I am making a game where the sprite I control has to get past another sprite moving back and forth. I am trying to make an if statement that says if the sprite I control is past a certain point, i win the game

writing something like

```
if mysprite.get_position() > (-100, 10):
    mysprite.say("I win!")
```

does not seem to work. I'm trying to figure out how to compare where its position is on the grid. thanks!

Comment: What type is mysprite?

Comment: ^I am using codesters tbh so I am not too sure. pretty sure it's just a basic sprite

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to elaborate the question. Your goals are a bit unclear.

Comment: To indent your code correctly here, you can just select it and press Ctrl+K or the `{}` button (that will add four extra spaces before each line).

Comment: If you just want to check if the x or y position of your sprite is past the point, do something like: `if mysprite.get_position()[0] > -100:`. You can't just [compare some tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5292303/6220679).

Answer (score 0):

The `Sprite` class on [codesters](https://www.codesters.com) appears to have `get_x` and `get_y` methods. You should be able implement your position check using something like this:

```
if my_sprite.get_y() > -100:
    my_sprite.say("I win!")
```

I was able to get an output console by clicking on the console button:

[image: the console button]

I added the following code to get a list of `Sprite` attributes and methods:

```
for entry in dir(sprite):
    print entry
```

I did not see `get_position` in the output.