# Maximum of nested tuple

Tags: python, nested, tuples, element

So I'm having trouble with printing out the largest number of a nested tuple. Let me backtrack here a bit. So I got a really good idea of how to separately print out elements, how to assign separated elements into a new tuple, and how to print out the largest number of a regular tuple. Well, I was given a challenge not that long ago that wants me to write a program that prints out the largest number of a **nested** tuple. At first, I thought this might be easy, but I keep printing out the same variables. Let me show you what I have so far.

```
my_nested_tuple = ((2,12), (24, 7), (9, 18), (22, 13))

def highest_element(l):
    my_max = l[0]
    for num in l:
        if my_max < num:
            my_max = num
    return my_max

print highest_element (my_nested_tuple)
```

This is as far as I gotten. The program keeps printing out (24,7), but I want it to print out the highest element only (which is 24).

Any help or hints will be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Keep in mind that I'm in the data structures lesson in intro computer science and haven't gone any further than that.

Comment: Will the tuples be arbitrarily nested, or only nested using the structure you've described here. In other words are these valid inputs: `((2,12,24),(1,2))`, `((2, (12, 24)), (1,2))`, `(2, (1,2))`?

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't work correctly. Try `my_nested_tuple = ((2,12), (24, 7), (9, 18), (1, 600))` and it still picks `(24,7)` because your code is comparing tuples, not integers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5292303/3901060

Comment: Not sure it is a duplicate: you are suggesting to combine two questions to answer this. Plus, it is not even the only approach (although the most general) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the maximum among the maximum values within each tuple.

Here is a short solution:

```
max(map(max, my_nested_tuple))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
max(max(el) for el in my_nested_tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, calculating a single `max` on a lazy generator.

```
from itertools import chain

my_nested_tuple = ((2,12), (24, 7), (9, 18), (22, 13))

max(chain.from_iterable(my_nested_tuple))

# 24
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to one tuple then using `max`

```
max(sum(my_nested_tuple,()))
Out[720]: 24
```

***Notice*** :

[***well, I don't have an online reference handy, but it is quadratic time, since + between sequences is linear. Indeed, the sum function itself prevents you if you try to use strings, e.g. see what happens if you try TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead] Finally, from the docstring: "This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may reject non-numeric types."***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772831/how-do-i-print-the-largest-number-in-a-nested-tuple#comment84547582_48772881)

Comment: this: `sum(my_nested_tuple,())` is an anti-pattern. Avoid it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I'm not doubting you, but do you have an online reference for that statement?

Comment: @Robᵩ well, I don't have an online reference handy, but it is quadratic time, since `+` between sequences is linear. Indeed, the `sum` function itself prevents you if you try to use strings, e.g. see what happens if you try `TypeError: sum() can't sum strings [use ''.join(seq) instead]` Finally, from the docstring: "This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may reject non-numeric types."

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
max(chain(*my_nested_tuple))
```

It flattens the tuple first, then computes the max.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it, first by the first element of each tuple and then by the second element, and finally compare the biggest of the two:

```
by_first = sorted(my_nested_tuple)
by_second = sorted(my_nested_tuple, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
print(max(by_first[-1][0], by_second[-1][1]))
```

Or use directly the max() function like this:

```
by_first = max(my_nested_tuple)[0]
by_second = max(my_nested_tuple, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[1]
print(max(by_first, by_second))
```

Comment: Why do you keep calling `list` on the tuple?

Comment: It does work, but I'm not that far into coding in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, you are right, there is no need for list(). I initially had in mind the list method .sort() and had to convert the tuple to the list first. Now I fixed it.