# selection sort problems(student marks)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I have a list, which represent the student with their test scores
`a = [['May', 81], ['Jack', 91], ['Mike', 52], ['Jeremy', 58], ['Mark', 71],['Sam',81],['Brian',61],['Yan',71]]`

I wish to use selection sort to sort the scores first then the student name in alphabetic order.

I am a beginner and only know how to sort a normal list like

```
a = [1,64,23,13]
```

will give: `a = [1,13,23,64]`

My selection sort code is here:

```
def sort(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        min_item = min(a[i:])
        index = a.index(min_item)
        a[i],a[index] = a[index],a[i]
    print(a)
```

How can i sort the scores first then the name?

Comment: What is the result when you use sort on a?

Comment: [['Brian', 61], ['Jack', 91], ['Jeremy', 58], ['Mark', 71], ['May', 81], ['Mike', 52], ['Sam', 81], ['Yan', 71]]

Comment: You want the lowest scores first?

Comment: yes, lowest scores first, if two students got the same marks, then alphabetical with student names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) can be use in conjunction with a custom key:

```
def selection_sort(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        min_item = min(lst[i:], key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
        index = lst.index(min_item)
        lst[i], lst[index] = lst[index], lst[i]
    print(lst)

a = [['Brian', 61], ['Jack', 91], ['Jeremy', 58], ['Mark', 71], ['May', 81], ['Mike', 52], ['Sam', 81], ['Yan', 71]]

selection_sort(a)
```

**Output**

```
[['Mike', 52], ['Jeremy', 58], ['Brian', 61], ['Mark', 71], ['Yan', 71], ['May', 81], ['Sam', 81], ['Jack', 91]]
```

The `key` *transforms* each element of `lst` in a tuple where the first element is the score, and the second element is the name. Note that the above solution assumes you want the lowest scores first.

**Further**

1. [How does tuple comparison work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python)

As a side note, the complexity of selection sort is `O(n^2)`, it will be best if you use the built in .sort method, complexity `O(nlogn)`. Example of usage:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[['Mike', 52], ['Jeremy', 58], ['Brian', 61], ['Mark', 71], ['Yan', 71], ['May', 81], ['Sam', 81], ['Jack', 91]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by **scores first, names second**, you can using [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) - [this will be faster than using `lambda` and avoids using python function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233476/sort-a-list-by-multiple-attributes)

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(a, key=itemgetter(1,0))
```

which will result in:

```
 [['Mike', 52],
 ['Jeremy', 58],
 ['Brian', 61],
 ['Mark', 71],
 ['Yan', 71],
 ['May', 81],
 ['Sam', 81],
 ['Jack', 91]]
```

Comment: Мне кажется наши решения гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = [['Brian', 61], ['Jack', 91], ['Jeremy', 58], ['Mark', 71], ['May', 81], ['Mike', 52], ['Sam', 81], ['Yan', 71]]
a = np.array(a)
a[a[:,1].argsort()]
```