# Python age calculator based on DOB

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am practicing by creating an age calculator which calculates age in years based on given date of birth.

However it doesn't work the way I intend it to function. I want to show age in year e.g 19 to the user when their age is 19 and month is less than 6 and if the month is more than 6 then I want to add 1 to the age in this case 19+1.

Can anyone create the same program with the same concept in a better way?  Please add some explanation so that it is easy for me to understand.

I am python beginner, so please excuse my bad code as well as my bad English. Thanks in advance for the help.

```py
from datetime import date

Doby,Dobm,Dobd =input("enter your DOB : i.e year,month,days  1999,02,08   : ").split(",")
born = date(year = int(Doby) , month= int(Dobm) , day= int(Dobd))
today = date.today()
age = today.year - born.year
condition = today.month - born.month
if condition >= 6 :
    age += 1
elif condition <= -6 :
    age -= 1
print(age)
```

Comment: Considering your requirements, this code works fine. Of course, your condition on `month` seems a bit off, because usually one would do `age -= 1` if `today.month < born.month` (since haven't reached the birthday yet). If it is past the birth month, the age is accurate. But if you are certain you need that 6 month difference check, with the associated +1 and -1, then your code works fine.

Comment: If you have no errors in your code, but want a review of how it can be written better, you can try asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your function

```
def years_of_age():
    from datetime import date, datetime
    dob = input("Please enter your DOB as mm-dd-yyyy: ")

    #time delta in days
    val = date.today().toordinal() - datetime.strptime(dob, "%m-%d-%Y").toordinal()

    # this is just so you can confirm, comment out the following 4 lines
    print("months {}, years {}".format(\
                                       int(datetime.fromordinal(val).strftime("%m")),\
                                       int(datetime.fromordinal(val).strftime("%Y"))\
                                      ))

    # conditional return based on the months figure
    if int(datetime.fromordinal(val).strftime("%m")) >=6:
        return int(datetime.fromordinal(val).strftime("%Y")) + 1
    else:
        return int(datetime.fromordinal(val).strftime("%Y"))
```

Here are a few examples

```
years_of_age()
```

Please enter your DOB as mm-dd-yyyy: 5-16-1976
months 1, years 44
44

```
years_of_age()
```

Please enter your DOB as mm-dd-yyyy: 7-16-1976
months 11, years 43
44

```
years_of_age()
```

Please enter your DOB as mm-dd-yyyy: 2-16-1977
months 4, years 43
43

- instance method `.toordinal()` converts a datetime object into a number of days since Jan 1 0000.
- the instance method `.strftime()` converts a string to a datetime object given that there are format directives datetime ("%m-%d-%Y").
- since you are a beginner I made sure to use python standard library packages, not because numpy is too advanced, because standard library packages are efficient, great and overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose today is `01/01/2019` and input is `12/06/1989`. The output we need is `29years` `and 7 months`.

```
   if  condition >= 0:
    Totmonth = condition 
  else:
     Totmonth = 12+condition 
      age -= 1

  print "age is" , age,"years and", Totmonth,"months"
```

Comment: Please edit your post so that it is code formatted and it respects Python formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I subtracted the int(age) from 'age' to get the decimal port of the age.

```
days_in_year = 365.2425    
age = (date.today() - born).days / days_in_year
decAge = age - int(age)
```

Then checked to see if the decimal portion is greater than 0.5 and set 'age' accordingly.

```
if decAge > 0.5 :
  age = int(age) + 1
else:
  age = int(age)
```

I think that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can just divide with no of days in a year and do rounding (round half up) to get the desired result. The below code should work.

```
from datetime import date

# Doby,Dobm,Dobd =input("enter your DOB : i.e year,month,days  1999,02,08   : ").split(",")
Doby, Dobm, Dobd = 1999, 11, 1
born = date(year=int(Doby), month=int(Dobm), day=int(Dobd))
today = date.today()

print(round((today-born).days/365.25))
```

Output:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my case I need age,month and day from birthday ,my function below,

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

def Calc(): 
born_date = "02-08-1999"
born = datetime.strptime(born_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
today = date.today()
curr_month = today.month
born_month = born.month

curr_day   = today.day
born_day   = born.day

if born_month > curr_month:
    month_diff = born_month - curr_month
else :
    month_diff = curr_month - born_month
    

if born_day > curr_day:
    day_diff = born_day - curr_day
else :
    day_diff = curr_day - born_day

    
age = today.year - born.year
print(str(age))
print(month_diff)
print(str(day_diff))
return " Your Age  : " + str(age) +"  Years   " + str(month_diff) +  "  Months  and " + str(day_diff) + "  Days"
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime

def age(dob, on_date=None):
    # By default, use the current date for on_date
    if on_date is None:
        on_date = datetime.date.today()
    # Subtracting the years gives age at *end* of year
    age = on_date.year - dob.year
    # Adjust if they haven't had their birthday yet.
    if (on_date.month, on_date.day) < (dob.month, dob.day):
        age -= 1
    return age
```

The last `if` statement takes advantage [of how Python compares tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python) so that if the months are the same, the comparison will be based on the day of the month.

```
>>> # Calculate my own age
>>> age(datetime.date(1982, 12, 21))
39
>>> # My age increases on my birthday.
>>> age(datetime.date(1982, 12, 21), datetime.date(2022, 12, 21))
40
```