# Creating a button in python

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I'm trying to make an interactive game for special needs children, where you click on a button and it moves the photo on. I need some help however as when I run my code, the console prints "..." as it should when you click on the button, and when you click away from the buttons it does not. All is working there. No matter where you click above or below a button, it recognises it as the button. So it cannot distinguish the y coordinate column as not part of the button's co-ordinates. Help would be appreciated! See photos: [Game window][1]...
Code:

````
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
#define variables
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
(width, height) = (700, 500)
x = 250
y = 100
mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mpress = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
Button1 = 'photos/buttonCow.png'
Button2 = 'photos/buttonDuck.png'
Button3 = 'photos/buttonHorse.png'
Button4 = 'photos/buttonSheep.png'

imageOption1 = pygame.image.load(Button1)
imageOption2 = pygame.image.load(Button2)
imageOption3 = pygame.image.load(Button3)
imageOption4 = pygame.image.load(Button4)


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game!')
screen.fill(background_colour)
running = True


def buttons():
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (200, 400):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (260, 430):
            print("horse")
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (300, 400):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (360, 430):
            print("duck")
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (400, 400):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (460, 430):
            print("cow")
    if pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (500, 400):
        if pygame.mouse.get_pos() <= (560, 430):
            print("sheep")


def displayOptions():
    screen.blit(imageOption1, (400, 400))
    screen.blit(imageOption2, (300, 400))
    screen.blit(imageOption3, (200, 400))
    screen.blit(imageOption4, (500, 400))


def whichAnimalFunc():
    whichAnimal = random.randint(0, 4)
    if whichAnimal == 1:
        image = pygame.image.load('photos/cow.png')
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))
        displayOptions()
        pygame.display.update()
    if whichAnimal == 2:
        image = pygame.image.load('photos/duck.png')
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))
        displayOptions()
        pygame.display.update()
    if whichAnimal == 3:
        image = pygame.image.load('photos/horse.png')
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))
        displayOptions()
        pygame.display.update()
    elif whichAnimal == 4:
        image = pygame.image.load('photos/sheep.jpg')
        screen.fill(WHITE)
        screen.blit(image, (x, y))
        displayOptions()
        pygame.display.update()
    else:
        pygame.QUIT


while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False  # allows quit button to work
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print(pos)
            buttons()
            whichAnimalFunc()
            pygame.display.update()```



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDCa0.png
````

Comment: IMHO, this code is going in a wrong direction. You have a lot of duplicate code which could be resolved by using object oriented design. That way you'll also get rid of all the variable names with numbers (you'll be able to use a list instead).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does tuple comparison work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python)

Comment: I think your current issue is related to the tuple comparison. You expect a comparison in a way like a 2D math coordinate system. That's not the case. Implement a function that takes 3 tuples as input (topleft, bottomright and current) and calculate the boolean logic for each x and y coordinate individually

Answer (score 4):

You have to check coordinates separately. And don't forget the button size:

```
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if mx >= 200 and my >= 400 and mx < 200 + imageOption3.get_width() and my < 400 + imageOption3.get_height():
    print("horse")
```

Also you can shorten whole thing using list (if you are not familliar with objects):

```
gameData = [
# (buttonX, buttonY, name) - will be extended by button image
[400, 400, 'Cow'],
[500, 400, 'Duck'],
#...
]

# load buttons:
for item in gameData:
    item.append(pygame.image.load("photos/button%s.png"%item[2]))

def displayOptions():
    for button in gameData:
        screen.blit(button[3], (button[0], button[1]))

def buttons():
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for button in gameData:
        bx, by = button[0], item[1]
        bw, bh = button[3].get_size()
        if mx >= bx and my >= by and mx < bx+bw and my < by+bh:
            print(button[2])

# etc.
```

Comment: Thanks VVend! Doesnt seem to work, however. Thanks for the quick reply but could you possibly help any more? I have tried the first suggestion, however I do not understand the entire shortening with lists bit. What happens now, with the first suggestion implemented, is that the game completely ignores the fact it is a button and prints nothing. Thanks.

Comment: First suggestion is replacement for your 'horse' condition in buttons() function and it should work.

Comment: 'List solution' uses list gameData containing buttons definitions. So you can just iterate list items instead of writing code for each button.

Comment: List version here: https://wendigo.online-siesta.com/hidden/animalguess.py

Answer (score 3):

You can't just say `pygame.mouse.get_pos() >= (200, 400)`, you have to say:

```py
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if mouse[0] >= 200 and mouse[1] >= 400:
   # hovering
```