# How python sorted method utilizes key lambda function's returned tuple and prioritises it for sorting

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

For example below is a call, and how generally will the interpreter use this tuple in sorting the string in a specific preference order

```
sorted(s,key = lambda x:(x.isdigit() and int(x)%2==0, x.isdigit(),x.isupper(),x.islower(),x))
```

But when the following code is executed, it results with the following output:
[image]

This is infact the solution to the following problem on hackerrank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ginorts/problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/1416672

Comment: What do you mean by "how generally will the interpreter use this"? Do you mean how the interpreter specifically runs this code, or what the algorithm behind this is? Do you know how ``sorted``'s ``key`` argument works, what a ``lambda`` function is, how booleans are compared, how tuples are compared, ...?

Comment: Thats what the question is about. How the key lambda function's tuple are compared

Answer (score 1):

It will compare the results of the lambda with `>` operators:

```
In [1]: (1,2) > (1,4)                                                                                   
Out[1]: False

In [2]: (2,2) > (1,4)                                                                                   
Out[2]: True

In [3]: (True, False) > (True, True)                                                                    
Out[3]: False
```

It's like comparing strings. First unequal element determines the result.

Comment: I think your explanation pretty much sums up the problem. So the preferences would be given to all the characters whose tuples have their bools to be true from right most side.

Answer (score 0):

The `key` function is called on each element of the list, and the value it returns is used as the sorting "key" (i.e. as the comparison value instead of the actual list elements).

Your sorting function is equivalent to:

```
def sort_key(x: str) -> Tuple[bool, bool, bool, bool, str]:
    return (
        x.isdigit() and int(x) % 2 == 0,
        x.isdigit(),
        x.isupper(),
        x.islower(),
        x
    )
```

(expanded into a function `def` with type annotations so we can better see what it's returning)

So I can infer that your list is of strings; the sorting key function is returning a tuple with four bool values that tell us different properties of those strings as True/False values.

1. It's an even number.
2. It's any kind of number.
3. It's all uppercase.
4. It's all lowercase.

And the fifth value is the string itself (which will be sorted alphabetically).  When tuples are compared, the first value is compared first, then the second, etc.  When bool values are compared, `False` comes before `True`.  So the sorted list is going to be grouped up in the above four categories in that order; you'll have even numbers grouped up first (at the end of the list, because `True` follows `False`), then odd numbers, then uppercase strings, then lowercase strings, then everything else.  Within those categories, sorting will happen by string order (lexicographically).

Comment: I also expected that, 

But unfortunately just look at this:

>>> s='azutyuyt234134678567'
>>> sorted(s,key = lambda x:(x.isdigit() and int(x)%2==0, x.isdigit(),x.isupper(),x.islower(),x))
['a', 't', 't', 'u', 'u', 'y', 'y', 'z', '1', '3', '3', '5', '7', '7', '2', '4', '4', '6', '6', '8']

Comment: Note that when bool values are sorted, `False` comes before `True`, so the high-precedence sorting criteria will put the matching items at the end and the non-matching items at the beginning!