# Order file based on numbers in name

Tags: python

I have a bunch of file with names as follows:

```
tif_files = av_v5_1983_001.tif, av_v5_1983_002.tif, av_v5_1983_003.tif...av_v5_1984_001.tif, av_v5_1984_002.tif...av_v5_2021_001.tif, av_v5_2021_002.tif
```

However, they are not guaranteed to be in any sort of order.

I want to sort them based on names such that files from the same year are sorted together. When I do this

```
sorted(tif_files, key=lambda x:x.split('_')[-1][:-4])
```

I get the following result:

```
av_v5_1983_001.tif, av_v5_1984_001.tif, av_v5_1985_001.tif...av_v5_2021_001.tif
```

but I want this:

```
av_v5_1983_001.tif, av_v5_1983_002.tif, av_v5_1983_003.tif...av_v5_1984_001.tif, av_v5_1984_002.tif...av_v5_2021_001.tif, av_v5_2021_002.tif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `v1` or `v2` or ... `v5` or ... you need to consider number of version also like below:

```
tif_files = ['av_v1_1983_001.tif', 'av_v5_1983_002.tif', 'av_v6_1983_002.tif','av_v5_1984_001.tif', 'av_v5_1984_002.tif', 'av_v4_2021_001.tif','av_v5_2021_001.tif', 'av_v5_2021_002.tif', 'av_v4_1984_002.tif']

sorted(tif_files, key=lambda x: [x.split('_')[2:], x.split('_')[1]])
```

Output:

```
['av_v1_1983_001.tif',
 'av_v5_1983_002.tif',
 'av_v6_1983_002.tif',
 'av_v5_1984_001.tif',
 'av_v4_1984_002.tif',
 'av_v5_1984_002.tif',
 'av_v4_2021_001.tif',
 'av_v5_2021_001.tif',
 'av_v5_2021_002.tif']
```

Comment: thanks, they are all `v5` and nothing else

Answer (score 2):

take the last two using `[2:]` for example `['1984', '001.tif']`

```py
tif_files = 'av_v5_1983_001.tif', 'av_v5_1983_002.tif', 'av_v5_1983_003.tif',\
            'av_v5_1984_001.tif', 'av_v5_1984_002.tif', 'av_v5_2021_001.tif', 'av_v5_2021_002.tif'

sorted(tif_files, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[2:])

# ['av_v5_1983_001.tif',
#  'av_v5_1983_002.tif',
#  'av_v5_1983_003.tif',
#  'av_v5_1984_001.tif',
#  'av_v5_1984_002.tif',
#  'av_v5_2021_001.tif',
#  'av_v5_2021_002.tif']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did was sorting it by the `00x` index first then by the year as `x.split('_')[-1]` produces `001` and etc. Try to change the index to sort by year first , then sort it again by the index:

```
sorted(tif_files, key=lambda x:x.split('_')[2])
sorted(tif_files, key=lambda x:x.split('_')[-1][:-4])
```

Comment: no need to sort twice you can give a list or tuple as a key like `[year, index]`

Answer (score 1):

As long as your naming convention remains consistent, you should be able to just sort them alphanumerically. As such, the below code should work;

`sorted(tif_files)`

If you instead wanted to sort by the last two numbers in the file name while ignoring the prefix, you would need something a bit more dramatic that would break those numbers out and let you order by them. You could use something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd
tif_files_list = [[xx, int(xx.split("_")[2]), int(xx.split("_")[3])] for xx in tif_files]
tif_files_frame = pd.DataFrame(tif_files_list, columns=["Name", "Primary Index", "Secondary Index"])
tif_files_frame_ordered = tif_files_frame.sort_values(["Primary Index", "Secondary Index"], axis=0)
tif_files_ordered = tif_files_frame_ordered["Name"].tolist()
```

This breaks the numbers in the names out into separate columns of a Pandas Dataframe, then sorts your entries by those broken out columns, at which point you can extract the ordered name column on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If `key` returns a tuple of 2 values, the `sort` function will try to sort based on the first value then the second value.
please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332/9532450

```py
tif_files = [
    "hea_der_1983_002.tif",
    "hea_der_1983_001.tif",
    "hea_der_1984_002.tif",
    "hea_der_1984_001.tif",
]


def parse(filename: str) -> tuple[str, str]:
    split = filename.split("_")
    return split[2], split[3]


sort = sorted(tif_files, key=parse)
print(sort)
```

output

```
['hea_der_1983_001.tif', 'hea_der_1983_002.tif', 'hea_der_1984_001.tif', 'hea_der_1984_002.tif']
```

Answer (score -2):

right click your folder and click sort by >> name.