# Python sorted function key

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, sorting

Please help me understand this Python3 code:

```
def length_and_alphabetical(string):
    """Return sort key: length first, then case-normalized string."""
    return (len(string), string.casefold())

colors = ["Goldenrod", "Purple", "Salmon", "Turquoise", "Cyan"]
colors_by_length = sorted(colors, key=length_and_alphabetical)
```

I understand what it's doing, but I don't understand how it's working.
The `length_and_alphabetical` function returns a tuple which contains two items, an `int` and a `string`, this tuple is used for comparison by the `sorted` function.

So for example the function may return `(9, "Goldenrod")`, but which of these is being used as the key? There's two options here, and you can't do a direct comparison on them as they're different object types.

I've been looking at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and I'm none the wiser.

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5292332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire tuple returned by `length_and_alphabetical` is treated as a single key. So when `sorted` has to compare `"Salmon"` and `"Goldenrod"`, it *really* compares `(6, "salmon")` to `(9, "goldenrod")`. Tuples are ordered lexicographically, just like strings, except the "letters" involved are elements of the tuple. So since `6 < 9` is true, `(6, "salmon") < (9, "goldenrod")` is *also* true, and `sorted` thus considers `"Salmon"` to precede `"Goldenrod"` in the sorted list.

When comparing `"Salmon"` and `"Purple"`, the function compares `(6, "purple")` and `(6, "salmon")`. Since `6` equals `6` and `"purple"` is less than `"salmon"`, `(6, "purple")` is considered smaller and `"Purple"` comes first in the sorted order.

---

Python 2 used to support *comparison* functions, which let you compare two values directly, rather than having to map both to some new value to be compared. While `key` is more efficient (it guarantees that the `key` function is called at most once per key), comparison functions are sometimes more direct and easy to follow. Fortunately, you can automatically convert any comparison function to an appropriate key using `functools.cmp_to_key`.

```
# -1 means x < y
# 0 means x == y
# 1 means x > y
def compare_colors(x, y):
    if len(x) < len(y):
        return -1
    elif len(x) > len(y):
        return 1
    elif x.casefold() < y.casefold():
        return -1
    elif x.casefold() > y.casefold():
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

colors_by_length = sorted(colors, key=cmp_to_key(compare_colors))
```

`compare_colors` would be a little simpler to define usingg the old built-in `cmp` function:

```
# def cmp(x, y):
#     return -1 if x < y else 1 if x > y else 0

def compare_colors(x, y):
    return cmp(len(x), len(y)) or cmp(x.casefold(), y.casefold())
```

Comment: Thank you. This may sound silly, but would I be correct in thinking that the `sorted` function reads all of it's input, and corresponding keys, then does a final comparison of all keys at the end to arrive at the final sorted list?

Comment: I think it's more accurate to say that `key` can be *deferred* until a comparison involving the element is needed, regardless of how many items have been retrieved from the iterable to be sorted so far. But once the key has been computed, it will be reused no matter how many comparisons to the element are made.

Comment: Thank you. I've marked your answer as the best one. You've been a great help.

Comment: @the_slug Actually your description is more accurate than chepner's. It creates a new list with the elements from the given source, then computes all the keys, then sorts the elements and their keys in parallel, by the keys.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's probably an implementation detail of `sorted` that you don't need to worry about (or rely on). `sorted` simply promises that `key` will be called once per element, and that the result is a sorted list.

Comment: @chepner Yes, might be an implementation detail, and I wouldn't rely on it other than for fun stuff. I think the sort() documentation does say it computes all keys before sorting, but sorted() doesn't quite say so and doesn't say it works like sort(), either.

Answer (score 1):

When Python compares two tuples, it compares them element by element.  If the first element of one is unequal to the first element of the other, it returns the result of that comparison.  Then it does the same for each succeeding element, stopping when it reaches one that's unequal.

In your case only strings of equal length will get to the comparison of the strings themselves.

If the elements are types that are not comparable, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the key function in sorting is that the key function is the criteria that the sort function will use to sort. Most of the times there is a default sorting criteria. For string, it is usually alphabetical sorting, but you can specify your own sorting criteria as you are doing in your code.

For you particular case, you are defining a sorting key that sorts by length. However, in the cases where two strings have the same length, `string.casefold()` will be used as a second criteria to decide which of the same-length strings go first. In other words, that will sort the same-length string alphabetically.

Comment: It may or may not do a secondary alphabetical search on equal length strings. As to whether it is alphabetic depends which language the strings belong to.

Answer (score -2):

sort will use the first element of the tuple in ascending order but the function will return tuple of tuple as you mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).