# How to structure a function that has to return a boolean by iterating over a possibly empty list?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Consider this function that accepts a tuple of three integers and then compares these integers to a list of tuples also consisting of three integers:

```
 def add_version_number(self, version_number: tuple[int, int, int]) -> bool:
    major, minor, patch = version_number
    for smajor, sminor, spatch in self.version_numbers:
        if major == smajor:
            if minor == sminor:
                if patch > spatch:
                    self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            elif minor > sminor:
                self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif major > smajor:
            self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The function is supposed to compare a version number (major, minor, patch) to a list of version numbers to see whether the new version number is bigger than the version numbers in the list.

Pylance complains that

```
Function with declared return type "bool" must return value on all code paths
  "None" is incompatible with "bool"
```

Which makes sense since the list is initially empty.

What would be best practice here? I could just append a default value to the function but that somehow feels clunky.

```
def add_version_number(self, version_number: tuple[int, int, int]) -> bool:
    major, minor, patch = version_number
    for smajor, sminor, spatch in self.version_numbers:
        if major == smajor:
            if minor == sminor:
                if patch > spatch:
                    self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            elif minor > sminor:
                self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif major > smajor:
            self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    self.version_numbers.append(version_number)
    return True
```

Comment: be careful if you plan to use a list as a default value for functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: If self.version_numbers is initially an empty list then your second code fragment is fine

Comment: Easy. Just add test for empty list `if not self.version_numbers:` at start of your function, before the `for` loop. If the list is empty, add the first version number and return `True`. It is common to get rid of these corner cases at start of your function. Also note that you can [compare tuples directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292303/how-does-tuple-comparison-work-in-python), which will make your code much shorter (and more readable).

Comment: @Jeyekomon Apologies, I haven't mentioned that I already tried `if not self.version_numbers:`. While it does work as intended Pylance still throws the `Function with declared return type "bool" must return value on all code paths`.

But thanks for the tuple comparison hint, that looks promising!

Comment: Also, I did not see that at the first time - you loop over all version numbers but then you return (True/False), immediately ending the loop and the whole function. You are effectively comparing the current version number with only the first one in the list, which is definitely not what you wanted and also probably confuses the Pylance linter. You don't have to compare the current version number with all of them in the list, only with the biggest one should be enough. Something like `max(version_numbers)` will select the biggest one in the list.

Comment: @Jeyekomon, that's embarassing, great catch! I rewrote the function to use tuple comparison, but without an explicit `else: return False` the linter doesn't let me get away. 
Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Your first function always returns on the first iteration of the loop, it doesn't search the whole list. It returns `None` if `self.version_numbers` is empty.